# cors with error in the console the error does not disappear

Tags: java, angular, spring, web

I'm trying to get rid of the cors error in the index but it's not working. I tried using the code @CrossOrigin(origins="*") but it didn't work. Is it because I'm using version 21 and in the video it uses version 17?

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")

public class Controller {
@Autowired
private Repositorio acao;

@PostMapping("/")

public Cliente cadastrar(@RequestBody Cliente c ){
return acao.save(c);
}
@GetMapping("/")
public Iterable<Cliente> teste(){
return acao.findAll();
}
 @Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
@PutMapping("/")
public Cliente editar(@RequestBody Cliente c){
return acao.save(c);
}
@DeleteMapping("/{codigo}")
public void remover(@PathVariable long codigo){
acao.deleteById(codigo);
}
}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iwuP.png)


[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeS0V.png)
```

I expected the error to disappear from the console

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format it properly --- Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- Why do you think that this is a CORS error? `405` means "method not allowed".

Comment: so at first I tried to just use the code @CrossOrigin(origins="*")
 but it didn't work so I tried the one you saw above because in the video he only used @CrossOrigin(origins="*")
it works